# Necesito obtener la MAC de un cliente en un proyecto web para autenticarlo con la la info en mi base de datos ¿hay alguna forma hacerlo?

Tags: javascript, primefaces, java-ee, spring-security, ejb

En la mayoría de información que he encontrado dicen que no se puede debido a que es muy bajo nivel para obtenerlo desde el cliente.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Es así, desde hace unas cuantas versiones de Windows tienen bloqueado el libre acceso a esa información.

Hace unos 5 años yo investigué y había posibildad solamente en algunas computadoras que tuviesen un Windows antiguo (XP) y que no tuviesen algunas actualizaciones en específico.

Comment: En mi opinión si necesitas un nivel de seguridad así de guapetón necesitas escribir un cliente de escritorio (la tecnología que  más te guste) para que tenga acceso a esa información. Si trabajas con `JS` a lo mejor te puedes dar un brinco a electrón e intentar algo como esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386371/get-the-mac-address-of-the-current-machine-with-node-js-using-getmac